# PHP NumberFormatter, formatCurrency method rounds number for Serbian dinar

Tags: php, rounding, numberformatter, format-currency

PHP NumberFormatter, formatCurrency method rounds numbers for Serbian dinar, but it works fine for other locales and currencies like Poland, Russia, and Turkey for instance.

```php
echo (new NumberFormatter('sr_RS',NumberFormatter::CURRENCY))
        ->formatCurrency('127.43','RSD');
// 127 дин.

echo (new NumberFormatter('ro_RO',NumberFormatter::CURRENCY))
        ->formatCurrency('127.43','RON');
// 127,43 RON

echo (new NumberFormatter('pl_PL',NumberFormatter::CURRENCY))
        ->formatCurrency('127.43','PLN');
//127,43 zł

echo (new NumberFormatter('tr_TR',NumberFormatter::CURRENCY))
        ->formatCurrency('127.43','TRY');
//127,43 ₺
```

So I want to show the decimals in the first case as well, is this a normal behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default currency number format for Serbia does not include decimal places - likely they are not often used or are ignored in that locale.

You can see the pattern used in this [ICU data table](https://intl.rmcreative.ru/number-formatting/sr_RS#numberformatter-patterns), under the NumberFormatter Patterns header and CURRENCY side-header. If you enter other locales in the search box at the top you will notice most use a format of `#,##0.00` whereas the `sr_RS` locale uses `#,##0`.

While likely bad practice since the ICU patterns are generally what the populous expects for each locale, you can ensure 2 digits are included by modifying the pattern (not guaranteed to be safe with every locale, but should not change most), by using a regular expression:

```php
$nf = new NumberFormatter('sr_RS', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$nf->setPattern(preg_replace('/##0(?!\.)/', '##0.00', $nf->getPattern()));
echo $nf->formatCurrency('127.43','RSD');
// 127,43 RSD
```

The pattern `##0(?!\.)` says to look for a string that starts with two hashtag/pound symbols followed by a zero that is not followed by a period and replace it with a pattern that does include 2 decimal places (`##0.00`).